# how to play private video from vimeo in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, vimeo

> what I'm getting from my Vimeo account is an id and token.

```
`var response = await http .get('https://player.vimeo.com/video/' + videoId + '/config');`.
```

> And I tried to get the video URL using. But since it is a private video
> not able to fetch URL using this method. Is there any better way to
> play private video from Vimeo?

Answer (score 1):

You have to authenticate in your Vimeo account that's own this video, and this can be do in many ways, i recommended to use the Access Token, that is a static token that can be storage on your backend database for security principles.

You can reach this authenticate ways [here](https://developer.vimeo.com/api/authentication).

After authenticate, you can reach any info about your videos doing a GET request:

**Url**: *[https://api.vimeo.com/videos/*[video_id]](https://api.vimeo.com/videos/*%5Bvideo_id%5D)

**Header**: {'Authorization': bearer [Access_Token]}

To more informations about this request, you can reach the [Vimeo official documentation](https://developer.vimeo.com/api/reference/videos#get_video).

Comment: i already have the token so should I authenticate in the Vimeo account. when i call this API with the token in a header it gives a 401 (unauthenticated).

Comment: What endpoint do you use to get your token?

Comment: After that how can I play the video in my Flutter app?